# ScrollArea and ScrollBar not working

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I've been trying to make a java swing based application to retrieve tweets from a user by using twitter4j..the code seems to be working when pretend on the console but not adding ..i've tried adding the scroll area and scroll bar to help with text wrapping and longer texts but it seems to be not working..

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;



public class mainTwitter {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<Status> statuses=null;
        String user;

try{

            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
              .setOAuthConsumerKey("*************")
              .setOAuthConsumerSecret("*************")
              .setOAuthAccessToken("*************")
              .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("*************");

            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());

            Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();




            if(args.length==1)
            {
                user=args[0];
                statuses=twitter.getUserTimeline(user);
            }
            else
            {
                user = twitter.verifyCredentials().getScreenName();
                statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline();

            }

            System.out.println("Showing "+user+"'s user timeline.");
        /*
            for(Status status: statuses)
            {
                System.out.println("@"+status.getUser().getScreenName()+"-"+status.getText());

            }*/

        }
        catch(Exception e)  
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Twitter Montior");

        mainFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        mainFrame.setLocation(360, 80);


        JPanel tPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();

        mainFrame.setLayout(null);


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    //Top Panel  

        JTextField t1 = new JTextField("Twitter Monitor!!");
            t1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            t1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            t1.setEditable(false);

            Font new_f = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 30);
            t1.setFont(new_f);


        JTextArea userInfo=new JTextArea();
            Font font2 = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20);
            userInfo.setFont(font2);
            userInfo.setLineWrap(true);
            userInfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            userInfo.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            userInfo.setEditable(false);
            userInfo.setLineWrap(true);

            JScrollPane scrollArea = new JScrollPane(userInfo);
                scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                JScrollBar bar = new JScrollBar();

                scrollArea.add(bar);

        tPanel.add(scrollArea);


        JButton retrieve = new JButton("Click");



        tPanel.setLayout(null);
        t1.setBounds(150, 2, 250, 30);
        userInfo.setBounds(0,34,700,260);
        retrieve.setBounds(260, 300, 50, 20);

        tPanel.add(retrieve);
        tPanel.add(t1);
        tPanel.add(userInfo);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////     

        ///Bottom Panel..







///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////     
        tPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 350);
        bPanel.setBounds(0,352,700,248);



        handler h = new handler(statuses, userInfo);
        retrieve.addActionListener(h);

        mainFrame.add(tPanel);
        mainFrame.add(bPanel);




        mainFrame.setSize(700, 600);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);








    }





}

class handler implements ActionListener
{
    List<Status> statuses2;
    JTextArea t;

    handler(List<Status> statuses1, JTextArea f)
    {

        statuses2=statuses1;
        t=f;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s = e.getActionCommand();

        if(s=="Click")
        {
            for(Status status: statuses2)
            {
                System.out.println("@"+status.getUser().getScreenName()+"-"+status.getText());
                t.setText("@"+status.getUser().getScreenName()+"-"+status.getText());
                t.setText("\n");

            }
        }



    }





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you use null layout, and you need to choose size and place of every components inside `mainFrame` and your panels. In my opinion is very bad idea and it is generally not recommended. It would be much simpler to write it with use of `BorderLayout` for `JFrame`, and other for your `JPanels`. But it is up to you.

It this particular case, in my opinion your `scrollArea` is not working because:

1. You add `userInfo` twice, first to `scrollArea`, then to `tPanel` directly. So what you see when you run program, is `userInfo` in `tPanel`, because components could be added to only one container.
2. You use a null layout so it is necessary to `setBounds()` for every component inside container with such layout settings, but you didn't `setBounds()` for `scrollArea`.

So the quickest way to make it work:

- delete line `tPanel.add(userInfo);`,
- change `scrollArea.setBounds(0,34,700,260);` for `userInfo.setBounds(0,34,700,260);` - it is enough to change component it relete to,

After those changes it should work.

***Aditional comments:***

- you dont't need to add `JScrollBar` to `JScrollPane`, it has it by itself,
- the `mainFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);` line is not working and it is not necessary, becouse you `setLocation()` of `mainFrame` manually and use null layout,
- you use `userInfo.setLineWrap(true);` twice, you can delete one line,

Comment: thanks, it works now..i've tried using layouts in past but i always ends up messing up with the whole frame..can you suggest any good tutorial on using layouts in swing application?

Comment: @NightOwl19 I think the [official](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) one is quite good

Comment: @NightOwl19 btw. if my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. It is not mandatory, but it shows other users, that my answer was useful, and gives some reputation for both of us.

Comment: Hey, as i mentioned the scroll bar was added to the frame and is now visible.but, another problem has occurred now...only the last line of all the tweets i'm trying to retrieve from the user's timeline is visible only. I don't know why as i have tried using the example given in the twitter4j docs.can you help me out here?

Comment: @NightOwl19 Are you use setText() or append()  for displaying tweets on your JTextArea?

Comment: i'm using the .setText() to display the tweets? and here's the example i'm directly involving in my code....: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Comment: @NightOwl19 I don't see a example of `setText()` usage in your link, which paragraph?? `setText()` replace a content of `JTextArea` with new one, while `append()` add a content to existing one. So as I don't exactly know how your code looks like, I would encurage you to try with: 1) `textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n" + //newtext//);` or 2) `textArea.append(//new text// + "\n");` and let me know how it works